# How to schedule quartz job to run every 3 business days?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz

Is it possible to schedule quartz job for every 3 business days ?

I'm seeing some examples time or specific day or month examples but how to write quartz expression every 3 business days with any month and any year ?

I have tried `0 0 */3 * 1-5 *` but got error day-of-week and a day-of-month is not implemented.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot specify *both* a day-of-week (`1-5`) and a day-of-month (`*/3`) - [one of them must be `?`](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html#notes).

<del>How about `0 0 0 ? * MON-FRI/3`? Or `0 0 0 ? * MON,THU,TUE,FRI,WED`?</del>

**EDIT**: I tested above - it does *not* work (the `/` only seems to work for non-intervals, and the `MON,THU,TUE,FRI,WED` gets normalized to `MON-FRI`).

Looking at the [source of the next-trigger-day-computation](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/blob/master/quartz-core/src/main/java/org/quartz/CronExpression.java#L1258), I am quite confident now that "every 3 business days" is *not possible* with a *single* Quartz Scheduler Cron-Expression.

What possibly could work would be a *collection* of expressions. The "Related" links on the right might give some inspiration.

Comment: @user2848031 Any feedback on my answer?